# SEO effect on forwarding from a similar domain name to our primary one

Tags: seo, domains, domain-forwarding

Our primary domain name is like `MyDomains.example`. We also own `MyDomain.example` that has never had anything on it.

Is there any downside or risk to put a simple forward from `MyDomain.example` to `MyDomains.example` (primary)?

The main reason for doing this would be for customers who attempt to access our site without the "s" on the end.

We don't want this new domain to index or affect our current `MyDomains.example`.

Comment: What do you mean by "forwarding"?  Do you mean "HTTP Redirect", "Framed redirect", "reverse proxy", or something else?

Comment: Just a redirect, so when someone visits MyDomain.example it goes to our primary domain MyDomain.examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to do what you propose, as long as you do not do any [domain masking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_masking).
Here's a [short yt video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHTK2tM_UyA).

Comment: thanks! Yeah, no masking, just a way for customers to not find a dead site. thanks!